# $\sigma$ finite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, i.e. exist finite $A_n\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $\bigcup A_n=\Omega,\mu(A_n)<\infty$.

$\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system with $\sigma(\mathcal P)=\mathcal  F$, can we find such $A_n\in\mathcal P$? (Is $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure on  $\mathcal{P}$?)

---

This problem is from "the uniqueness of measure extension":

If $\nu_1,\nu_2$ are two measure that agree on $\mathcal{P}$, then they agree on $\sigma(\mathcal{P})$ under the condition that $\nu_i$ is $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathcal{P}$.

I wonder if it can be replaced by $\sigma$-finite measure on  $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal P)$. I got stuck on the final step on the original proof. (Refer to Durrett http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf page 361 thm A1.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\nu_1$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\nu_2=2\nu_1$. These are both $\sigma$ finite on the Borel sets ${\cal B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\nu_1=\nu_2$ on 
${\cal P}=\{(-\infty, x]: x\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which generates ${\cal B}(\mathbb{R})$.